# HTML 100% height bigger than window

Tags: html, css, height

I'm working on a layout with a vertical header at the top with a width of 100% of the browser window and below two columns. A sidebar on the left and a main column and both should cover the rest of the window.

Here is the Problem:
If the header got a height of 45px and the sidebar got a height of 100% the height together will be (100% + 45px) which means the whole side is bigger than the browser window. How can I solve this problem?

At the end I want to be able tenter code hereo separately scroll in the main and the sight bar and the header should be fixed at the top.

Here is a little example: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sfJuzCA2uSeglFrEdkDv?s=0qJrKMTQtgN4LQW1&p=preview)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

html, body, #wrapper, #main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header, #main {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Header */
header {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: green;
}

header div {
  float: left;
}

header #right {
  float: right;
}


/* Main */
#main section {
  float: left;
}

#main #sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 190px;
  height: 100%;
}

#main #content {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

 <body>
   <div id="wrapper">
   <header>
      Header
   </header>
   <div id="main">
    <section id="sidebar">
     Sidebar
    </section> <!-- #sidebar -->
    <section id="content">
     Content
    </section> <!-- #content -->
   </div><!-- #main -->
  </div><!-- #wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: Position: absolute could work

Comment: if your header height is static you could use `height: calc(100% - 45px);`. note that this is css3 and wont work in old browsers. [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: Your suggestion `height: calc(100% - 45px);` unfortunately doesn't solve the problem. The two sections are now at the exact height but there is a white space now at the bottom with the height of 45px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping your `header` fixed will solve this. Add `position: fixed` to the `header` and that will do.

Let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Added this to the `sidebar` and `content`:

```
  height: calc(100% - 45px);
  padding-top: 45px;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

html, body, #wrapper, #main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header, #main {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Header */
header {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
}

header div {
  float: left;
}

header #right {
  float: right;
}


/* Main */
#main section {
  float: left;
}

#main #sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 190px;
  height: calc(100% - 45px);
  padding-top: 45px;
}

#main #content {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: calc(100% - 45px);
  padding-top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

 <body>
   <div id="wrapper">
   <header>
      Header
   </header>
   <div id="main">
    <section id="sidebar">
     Sidebar
    </section> <!-- #sidebar -->
    <section id="content">
     Content
    </section> <!-- #content -->
   </div><!-- #main -->
  </div><!-- #wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi kukkuz,
thank you for your reply. Your solution looks good but now the texts ("Sidebar" and "Content") are behind the header. And a margin or padding statement would cause the initial problem.

Comment: of course it will.. as the `sidebar` and `content` are at 100%

Comment: @make: edited the answer- check it out now and let me know your feedback?

Comment: yes they got 100% height but the text in sidebar and content is now behind the header what creates another problem.

Comment: @make not behind header now.

Comment: @make so is everything fine here?

Comment: thank you this looks fine now. But I assume calc is a CSS3 feature, which won't work in older browsers?

Comment: depends on your target end-users, its all fine if you do not want support of the old IE8 (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)